# Add Existing SQLite Database in Windows Phone Application?

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-7.1

I am very new to windows phone application development and I am working on a Windows 7.1 Phone Application in which I have to use an existing database which is SQLite. I am wondering how to add that file in the project and then how can I query that database? How to add helper classes for this db?I have searched around but I was not able to find an easy to understand tutorial. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/

Project Description
Sqlite client for Windows Phone 7 with transaction support
You can find more details on my blog:
http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com
Last edited Nov 30, 2010 at 1:16 PM by dan_ardelean, version 4

Comment: Some examples for how your code works would be great before trying to get us to build and run it.